# Insert and play audio clips based on a condition in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

### Objective

Create a shiny app for navigation on a road network. The app must play voice prompts using the audio clips at specified locations.

### Problem

The `insertUI` and `removeUI` show the audio clips. But the app sometimes plays the same audio clip repeatedly and do not play other audio clips at all. **How can I effectively use `insertUI` to play only the relevant audio clip and play it only once?**

### Data, code and audio files

All files are available to download [here.](https://uwin365-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/durraniu_uwindsor_ca/ElwO2FG_vS5Bg0N7lcTAJGsB8bhzufJ5-sPONJjabvAGNA?e=JFoMcC)

### Simulated position data

The actual position data is obtained from a driving simulator. But for the sake of this reproducible example, I am simulating data in the `simulate_driving_sim_data.R` file. Following is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
load("pos_df.Rda")

names(pos_df) <- c("frames", "x", "y")

pos_df2 <- pos_df %>%
  dplyr::slice(which(row_number() %% 100 == 1))


for (i in 1:nrow(pos_df2)){
  
  dataa <- pos_df2[i,]
  
  print(dataa)
  
  
  
  write.csv(dataa, paste0("sampled", gsub("[^0-9]","",Sys.time()),".csv"),
            row.names = FALSE)
  
  Sys.sleep(1)
  
}
```

### Shiny app

As the `simulate_driving_sim_data.R` file generates the data, I run the shiny app in another Rstudio session. The app code is in `dashboard_New_v_demo.R`, shown below. The section of the app relevant to this question is under `## Play the navigation audio clip`.

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)


# Global------------------------------------------------------------------------


## Load the road network
load("df.Rda")


## Load the complex route
load(file = "pos_df.Rda")


## Load Music files
addResourcePath("Music", "Music")
# audio_file1 <- "Music/l1.mp3"
# audio_file2 <- "Music/l2.mp3"
# audio_file3 <- "Music/l3.mp3"


audio_file_200_TL <- "Music/in 200 m turn left.mp3"
audio_file_200_TR <- "Music/in 200 m turn right.mp3"
audio_file_TL <- "Music/turn left at the intersection.mp3"
audio_file_TR <- "Music/turn right at the intersection.mp3"





# User Interface ---------------------------------------------------------------
ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "black", 
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(
                       # menuItem("Music", tabName = "music", icon = icon("music")),
                       menuItem("Navigation", tabName = "navigation", icon = icon("compass"))
                      )),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        # First tab content
                        tabItem(tabName = "navigation",
                                fluidRow(
                                  tags$style(type="text/css", ".recalculating {opacity: 1.0;}"),
                                  plotOutput("plot1")
                                ),
                                
                                fluidRow(
                                  column(width = 8, valueBoxOutput("text"),tags$style("#text {width:600px;}")),
                                  column(width = 2, imageOutput("myImage")),
                                  tags$div(id = "AUDIO_MY")
                                )
                        )#,
                        
                        # Second tab content
                        # tabItem(tabName = "music",
                        #         h2("Music"),
                        #         fluidRow(
                        #           tags$audio(src = audio_file1, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = NA, controls = TRUE)
                        #         )    
                        #           
                        # )
                      )
                    )
)













# Server -----------------------------------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  ## Get the simulated position data
  
  IsThereNewFile=function(){  #  cheap function whose values over time will be tested for equality;
    #  inequality indicates that the underlying value has changed and needs to be 
    #  invalidated and re-read using valueFunc
    
    filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
    length(filenames)
  }
  
  
  
  ReadAllData=function(){ # A function that calculates the underlying value
    filenames <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE)
    readr::read_csv(filenames[length(filenames)])
  }
  
  
  
  
  
  position <- reactivePoll(300, session,IsThereNewFile, ReadAllData)    
  
  
 
  
  
  
  
  ## Plot
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    
    
    ### Get the zoomed-in surroundings of the position
    xl1 <-  position()$x - 500
    xl2 <-  position()$x + 500
    
    yl1 <-  position()$y - 300
    yl2 <-  position()$y + 300
    
    
    ggplot() +
      geom_path(data = df,
                aes(x, -y,
                    group = interaction(elem_idx, path_idx)),
                color = "grey50") +
      
      geom_path(data = pos_df, mapping = aes(ED_x, ED_y),
                color="skyblue", size = 2, alpha = 0.6) +
      geom_point(data = position(),
                 aes(x, y),
                 fill = "#4285F4", 
                 color = "white", 
                 size = 5, 
                 pch=21,
                 stroke = 3) +
      coord_equal(    xlim = c(xl1, xl2),
                      ylim = c(yl1, yl2)) +
      theme_void()
    
  })
  

  
  
  
  ## Generate a message
  msg <- reactive({
    
    
    if (position()$x > 34421.9 & position()$x < 35314.04 & position()$y < -2950 ) {
      
      msg <- "In 200 m Turn left"
      
      
      
      
      
    } else if (position()$x > 35936 & position()$x <  36004 & position()$y > 300 & position()$y < 986.373 ) {
      
      msg <- "In 200 m Turn right"
      
      
      
      
      
    } else if (position()$x > 37896 & position()$x < 38615) {
      
      msg <- "Turn left at the intersection"
      
      
      
      
    } else if (position()$x > 39120 & position()$x < 39336  & position()$y > 908 & position()$y < 2282.4727 ) {
      
      msg <- "In 200 m Turn right"
      
      
      
      
    } else if (position()$x > 39915 & position()$x < 40603.00 & position()$y > 2282 & position()$y < 2363) {
      
      msg <- "Turn left at the intersection"
      
      
      
      
    } else if (position()$y > 5530 & position()$y < 6261.8098) {
      
      msg <- "Turn left and park in the parking lot"
    
      
      } else {
      
      msg <- ""
    }
    
    print(msg)
    
    
    
  })
  
  
  ## Show the message
  output$text <- renderValueBox({
    
    
    valueBox(
      value = tags$p(msg(), style = "font-size: 90%;"),
      subtitle = "",
      color =  "light-blue",
      width = NULL
    )
  })

  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  ## Show the image
  output$myImage <- renderImage({
    
    if (msg() %in% c("In 200 m Turn right")) {
      
      return(
        
        # Generate the PNG
        list(src = "turn_right.png",
             width = 100,
             height = 100)
        
      ) 
    } else if (msg() %in% c("In 200 m Turn left",
                            "Turn left at the intersection",
                            "Turn left and park in the parking lot")) {
      
      return(
        
        # Generate the PNG
        list(src = "turn_left.png",
             width = 100,
             height = 100)
        
      )
    } else {
      
      return(
        
        # Generate the PNG
        list(src = "continue.png",
             width = 100,
             height = 100)
        
      )
      
    }
    
    
   
    
  }, deleteFile=FALSE)
  
  
  
  
  ## Play the navigation audio clip
  observeEvent(position(), {
    
    if (position()$x > 34421.9 & position()$x < 34600) {
      
      
      
      insertUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY",
               where = "afterEnd",
               ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file_200_TL, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA)
               , immediate = TRUE)
      
    } else if (position()$x > 35936 & position()$x <  36004 & position()$y > 300 & position()$y < 986.373) {
      
      removeUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY")
      
      insertUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY",
               where = "afterEnd",
               ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file_200_TR, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA)
               , immediate = TRUE)
      
    } else if (position()$x > 37896 & position()$x < 38615 & position()$y < 935 & position()$y < 370) {
      
      removeUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY")
      
      insertUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY",
               where = "afterEnd",
               ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file_TL, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA)
               , immediate = TRUE)
      
    } else if (position()$x > 39120 & position()$x < 39336  & position()$y > 908 & position()$y < 2282.4727) {
      
      removeUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY")
      
      insertUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY",
               where = "afterEnd",
               ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file_200_TR, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA)
               , immediate = TRUE)
      
    } else if (position()$x > 39915 & position()$x < 40603.00 & position()$y > 2282 & position()$y < 2363) {
      
      removeUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY")
      
      insertUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY",
               where = "afterEnd",
               ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file_TL, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA)
               , immediate = TRUE)
      
    } else if (position()$y > 5530 & position()$y < 6261.8098) {
      
      removeUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY")
      
      insertUI(selector = "#AUDIO_MY",
               where = "afterEnd",
               ui = tags$audio(src = audio_file_TL, type = "audio/mp3", autoplay = TRUE, controls = NA)
               , immediate = TRUE)
      
    } 
    
    
    
  })

  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Demo app image

[image]